# C adding and searching parsed data in array

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, pointers, segment

I'm trying to parse a string into smaller ones, extracting some values and then I want to check if any of these values is a dupe...

Here's my lame code :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="INVITE sip:alice1@open-ims.test SIP/2.0\nCall-ID: mndfdnf8e4953t984egnue@open-ims.test To: <sip:alice2@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice4@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice5@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice6@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice8@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice9@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice10@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice11@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice12@open-ims.test>;";
  char * tch;
  char * saved;  
char * array[50];
int count = 0;        
  tch = strtok (str,"<:;>");
    while (tch != NULL)
  { 
    int savenext = 0;              
    if (!strcmp(tch, "sip"))   
    {                             
      savenext = 1;                
    }                               
    printf ("%s\n",tch);
    tch = strtok (NULL, "<:;>");
    if (savenext == 1)             
    {                              
      saved = tch;                  
    }                              

if ( count == 0 ) {
    array[count] = saved;  
    count ++;  
    }
    if ( count > 0 ) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < count ) {
            if (array[count] == saved ) {
                printf("FOUND!");
                }
                i++;}
                }


            }
 }
```

What I have to do is check if the same username is found twice in the string, but my lack of experience with pointers prevents me from this. I can't figure out why the values won't be added to the array.

Any help is welcome and appreciated

Comment: exactly how do you want to parse. please elaborate a bit more. i could not understand.

Comment: I would like to extract all the "alice" values and check if any of those is used twice. If it is found twice, then it should print a message.

Comment: Say, we extract the values alice1, alice2, alice, alice4, alice....Then the programm must see that 'alice' is found twice in the string and print an alert. I hope I made myself a little bit more clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done

```
if ( count == 0 ) {
array[count] = saved;  
count ++;  
}
```

Which means that you save the address of the `saved` into `array[count]`. In this operation no strings were copied.

Then you do:

```
if (array[count] == saved ) {
  printf("FOUND!");
}
```

The above compares the value stored in `array[count]` with the address stored in `saved`. This operation does not compare the strings stored in them.

So if an address `0x1234abcd` in `array[count]`  points to a string "alice" and `saved` points to the string "alice" stored in another memory location `0xdeadbeef` then `array[count] == string` would not be same as in this case `0x1234abcd == 0xdeadbeef` is being done. To compare the two strings you need to do `strcmp (array[count], saved) == 0` .

Note that you do

```
    while (i < count ) {
        if (array[count] == saved ) {
            printf("FOUND!");
            }
      i++;
     }
```

In the above code, you have incremented `i` but accessed the `array` with `count` which is static for one pass, and does not depend on `i`. It should be `array[i]`

You have done

```
if (count == 0)
{
   array[count] = saved;  
   count ++
}
if (count > 0)
{
  /* Here you try to search if the 'saved' is in the aray
     but if it is not there you have NOT inserted it anywhere 
     into the array
   */
}
```

Because you do not enter the string pointed by `saved` when `count > 0` so the unique strings except the first one *does not* gets stored in the `array`. So you should save the new sting into the array whenever you find that it is not in the sting in the `if (count > 0)` block. Like as described in the following segment:

```
  if (count > 0)
    {
      int i = 0;
      while (i < count)
        {
          /* note use of strcmp */
          if (strcmp (array[i], saved) == 0)
            {
              printf ("FOUND!"); /* if it was found break immediately */
              break;
            }
          i++;
        }
       if (i == count) /* if there was no match then only i == count  */
        {              /* in other cases when dupes are there i<count as we used break */
          array[count] = saved;
          count++;
        }

    }
```

Here is the modified code, which reflect the above changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void)
{
  char str[] =
    "INVITE sip:alice1@open-ims.test SIP/2.0\nCall-ID: mndfdnf8e4953t984egnue@open-ims.test To: <sip:alice2@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice4@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice5@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice6@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice8@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice9@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice10@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice11@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice12@open-ims.test>;";
  char *tch;
  char *saved;
  char *array[50];
  int count = 0, i;

  tch = strtok (str, "<:;>");
  while (tch != NULL)
  {
      int savenext = 0;
      if (!strcmp (tch, "sip"))
  {
      savenext = 1;
      }
     // printf ("%s\n", tch);
     tch = strtok (NULL, "<:;>");
     if (savenext == 1)
 {
   saved = tch;
 }

    if (count == 0)
    {
  array[count] = saved;
  count++;
    }
    else if ((count > 0) && (savenext == 1))
    {
      int i = 0;
      while (i < count)
      {
        if (strcmp (array[i], saved) == 0)
    {
      printf ("FOUND!");
      break;
    }
        i++;
      }
      if (i == count)
      {
        array[count] = saved;
        count++;
      } 

    }
     }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
       printf ("\n%s", array[i]);
}
```

**EDIT1:**

Answer to your comment:
Say the `strtok` has matched "sip" , then it makes `saveptr = 1` reads in the next and token in `tch` , ie, the username info and saves it into `array` with the help of `saveptr`. In the next iteration note that `tch` points to the username info that was stored in  the array. So the `strcmp` fails as it is not "sip" (contains the user name info). So in this case the `saved` is although not modified it still holds the previous value, which enters the `if (count > 0)` block again. So one user information is checked *twice* in your process. You should do

```
if ((count > 0) && (savenext == 1))
{
     /* Then insert */
}
```

What the above code says that, if `saveptr ==` then the `saved` needs to be saved in the `array`, that is why you took the flag `savenext`.

I have updated the code too. Now it correctly tells that there is only one duplicate.

I would recommend to redesign the code and make it a bit more clean. Probably you would like to have another look about the pointers in details to make it better.

Comment: Wow, phoxis, these are a lot of helpful comments. I really appreciate your help. However, when I run the programm I get the "FOUND" message printed, even if the username is not found ( for example if I use `char str[] =
    "To: <sip:alice2@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice3@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice4@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice5@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice6@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice7@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice8@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice9@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice10@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice11@open-ims.test>;<sip:alice12@open-ims.test>;";`

Then the same username is not found, but the message gets printed.

Comment: Thanks phoxis. You have been extremely helrpfull!